# json to avro conversion for name fiield with special characters

Tags: json, scala, avro

Has Any one done a Json to Avro conversion without an Avro schema. The catch here is json has special characters in the name field so avr04s is failing.For dynamicity I need to to create the avro file straight from JSON. If that is not possible , I can create a case class or pojo with special characters . But all the name field will have one or the other kind of special character.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach ONE**

Create simple table with One column.

```
CREATE TABLE jsonTbl(line String)
```

Load json data into table

```
LOAD DATA INPATH  '/user/demo/pg54505.txt' INTO TABLE jsonTbl;
```

Create AVRO table in Hive

```
CREATE TABLE as_avro(ID String, ename String, esal Int) STORED AS AVRO;
```

Insert data to AVRO table using get_json_object()

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE as_avro SELECT get_json_object(fieldname, '$.emp.ID'), get_json_object(fieldname, '$.emp.ename'), get_json_object(fieldname, '$.ename.esal') FROM jsonTbl
```

OR
**Approach TWO**

Create external table with JsonSerDe and location where Json file is placed.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE jsonTbl(id string, ename string, esal int) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' LOCATION '/user/demo/';
```

Create AVRO table in Hive

```
CREATE TABLE as_avro(ID String, ename String, esal Int) STORED AS AVRO;
```

Insert data to AVRO table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE as_avro SELECT ID, ename, esal) FROM jsonTbl
```

Comment: I was asking for an approach in Scala or java where you convert a json to avro using code